# How to determine the current text scaling?

Tags: revert-buffer, scaling

When I type `C-x C-+` the height of the default face in the current buffer is increased. However, when I revert the buffer, the text scaling is reset to normal. I would like to keep the same scaling after reverting the buffer.

Is there a way to determine the amount of scaling in the current buffer, in order to save it and restore the same scaling when a buffer is reverted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variable `text-scale-mode-amount` holds the number of `text-scale-mode` steps. (Variable `text-scale-mode-step` holds the amount to scale for each step.)

Save `text-scale-mode-amount`, then later pass it to `text-scale-increase`.

Comment: Thanks, this works well together with `before-revert-hook` and `after-revert-hook`..

Comment: @HåkonHægland could you share your solution? I have the following, but doesn't seem to work: https://gist.github.com/ustun/f5b5eb447c0e7a02ef67a90324bd8f28

Comment: Actually, seems to work. I had some other hook that was ruining it.